# How to exhaust a generator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iteration, generator

I implemented `every` as a generator to break the iteration prematurely:

```
const every = (f, iter) => function* () {
  for (const value of iter) {
    const ret = f(value);
    yield ret;
    if (!ret) break;
  }
} ();

const exhaustEvery = iter => {
  for (value of iter) {
    if (!value)
      return false;
  }

  return true;
};

exhaustEvery(every(x => x % 2 === 1, [1,3,5])); // true
```

This seems quite cumbersome, because I must implement an individual exhaust function for each iteration function. Does this indicate incorrect usage of generators?

Comment: why do you need a generator?

Comment: I would only want to use a generator function as soon as I intend to _not_ exhaust an iterator in one go.

Comment: @NinaScholz I want every (and other iterative functions) to be data structure agnostic and I need early exit trait

Answer (score 2):

It makes little sense that `every` is a generator as it does not generate values itself, it just returns true or false, so it could just be:

```
 function every(iterator, predicate) {
    let value, done;
    do {
      ({ value, done } = iterator.next());
      if(!predicate(value)) return false;
    } while(!done)
    return true;
}

every([1, 2, 3].values(), it => it < 3) // false
```

Comment: @carcigenicate this is still lazy, the iterator will only get consumed till the first falsy value was found

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about it wrong. My bad.

Comment: This works only for every, not for other iterative functions.

Comment: @dafunc right, but the question was about `every` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're generator will end (which generators don't guarantee), you can spread the values with `[...res]`. In the case of your generator, you can then just look at the last value:

```js
const every = (f, iter) => function*() {
  for (const value of iter) {
    const ret = f(value);
    yield ret;
    if (!ret) break;
  }
}();


let res = [...every(x => x % 2 === 1, [1, 3, 5])]; // true
console.log(res[res.length - 1])

res = [...every(x => x % 2 === 1, [1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 5, 9])]; // false
console.log(res[res.length - 1])
```

But if you're doing all this just to generate a list from a generator, there may be a better way with a simple function.

Comment: This is interesting but not very efficient in this and probably other cases, because it may create a huge intermediate value.

Comment: @DaFunc, yes it does. If it's efficiency you're after, it's not at all clear why you are creating a generator and then iterating over it rather than just calling `array.every()` on the input.

Answer (score 0):

There are generators that cannot be exhausted, for example:

```js
function *fibonacci(n) {
  const infinite = !n && n !== 0;
  let current = 0;
  let next = 1;
  
  while (infinite || n--) {
    yield current;
    [current, next] = [next, current + next];
  }
}

// let [...first10] = fibonacci(10);
// alert(first10);
// the above is finite generator and shows how you can exhaust it,
// but what if it is initiated like the following:

let noexhaust = fibonacci();
alert(noexhaust.next().value);
alert(noexhaust.next().value);
alert(noexhaust.next().value);
alert(noexhaust.next().value);
// and so on...
```

So what should be the behaviour of your code, if it is facing a never ending generator?